# Prevent rendering of the desktop selection rectangle

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, desktop

I'm working on small program that basically animates the wallpaper using OpenGL.

The wallpaper is all interactive(I use a global mouse hook for the mouse events), but to make it perfect when I hold down the left mouse button, I'd like the selection rectangle to not appear at all.

All I could change was disable the **translucent selection rectangle** using a registry key and a P/Invoke function to force the desktop to reload it's registry settings, resulting in this:
[image: Screenshot]

On the image you can see the selection outline which would be great if wasn't rendered when I hold and drag.

Is it possible to achieve using C#?

**EDIT:**

There is a *partial* solution to this problem that @Jonathan Potter provided:

```
W32.EnumChildWindows(W32.GetDesktopWindow(), (hwnd, param) =>
{
    var WM_CANCELMODE = 0x001F;

    var sb = new StringBuilder(256);
    if (W32.GetClassName(hwnd, sb, 256) > 0)
    {
        if (sb.ToString() == "SysListView32")
            W32.SendMessage(hwnd, WM_CANCELMODE, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    }
    return true;
}, IntPtr.Zero);
```

The problem with this solution is that now whenever I try selecting anything on the desktop, it won't, since I am literally cancelling the selection just as I begin holding the mouse button.

Comment: It'll never stop puzzling me, why someone would write code to turn a good UI into a bad UI.

Comment: @IInspectable ...the point is not to make the UI look 'bad' but instead make it not cover the wallpaper

Comment: How are your users meant to know what they're selecting?

Comment: @MineR the program is configurable so I can just add it as an option to toggle. Besides, it will be invisible only when the focused window is the desktop, which I *can* do.

Comment: I actually want to render my own selection rectangle, but the one shown on the picture is still there :/

Comment: Inject code in the desktop process, sub-class the listview, intercept the `WM_MOUSEMOVE` message and make it send the listview a `WM_CANCELMODE` message if the mouse button is already down, maybe.

Comment: @JonathanPotter that actually worked! Now I can't select any icons on the desktop tho :D

Comment: You could implement your own selection logic, if you're sub-classing the window anyway. When the mouse button goes down check if it's over an icon using `LVM_HITTEST`, if not go into a modal loop drawing your own selection rectangle until the button is released.

Comment: Could you please provide an example of how I could use that? I'm not that experienced with the WinAPI..

Comment: If you aren't experienced with Win32 then you need to become experienced. Having us write your program for you isn't what this site is about. Good luck.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the reason I said that was because I don't see how what he described in his comment would resolve my issue. I'm not asking anyone for complete code. I need more descriptive answers than that one. Stop hating on me every time I post anything.

Comment: I'm trying to make the point that you cannot reasonably expect to succeed in this endeavour unless you are a Win32 expert. Having somebody else write code for you won't get you there. You need to do the hard yards.